# Error when calling input("Enter the sentence: ")

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, input, syntax-error

```
import random

sentence = input("Enter the sentence: ")
sentence=sentence.lower()
languages=[['hello','goodbye','thank you',"you\'re welcome",'have','a','nice','day','how','are','you'],
               ['ola','Tehau','obrigado','seja bem-vindo','ter','uma','bom','dia','como','esta','voce'],
               ['hello','faida','Asante','karibu','kuwa na','a','nzuri','siku','vipi','ni','wewe'],
               ['hallo','Vaarwel','dank je','graag gedaan','habben','een','leuk','dag','hoe','ziin','u'],
               ['hola','adios','gracias','De nada','tener','un','bonito','dia','como','son','tu']]
t=''

if sentence == "have a nice day":
    words=sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        i=languages[0].index(word)
        r=random.randint(1,4)
        t+=languages[r][i]+' '
elif sentence == "goodbye":
    i=languages[0].index(sentence)  
    r=random.randint(1,4)   
    t+=languages[r][i]
elif sentence == "hello":
    i=languages[0].index(sentence)
    r=random.randint(1,4)  
    t+=languages[r][i]
elif sentence == "you're welcome":
    i=languages[0].index(sentence) 
    r=random.randint(1,4)
    t+=languages[r][i]
elif sentence== "thank you":
    i=languages[0].index(sentence)
    r=random.randint(1,4)
    t+=languages[r][i]
elif sentence== "how are you":
    words=sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        i=languages[0].index(word)
        r=random.randint(1,4)
        t+=languages[r][i]+' '

print("The translated sentence is",t)
```

I got this error on `sentence=input("Enter the sentence")`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lab3.py", line 3, in <module>
    sentence = input("Enter the sentence: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    have a nice day
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Edit the full error traceback into the question, please.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? If you're using Python 2, you should use `raw_input()`

Comment: @Barmar: Given the `print` at the end has parentheses, I'm guessing it's intended to be Python 3. Can't be certain, though.

Comment: Try running your code with python3.

Comment: codio@domino-basic:~/workspace$ python Lab3.py
Enter the sentence: have a nice day
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lab3.py", line 3, in <module>
    sentence = input("Enter the sentence: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    have a nice day
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: that's the error that i'm getting

Comment: You should have used [edit] to add it into the question. Now someone else tried – and it's a different error!

Comment: we're using Cordio on the class so what i need to do to correct this program on cordio?

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by **executing Python 3 code with Python 2**.

#### If you want to use Python 3

Your program works fine for me when executed with Python 3. Just use the `python3` command to run it:

```
python3 you_code.py
```

#### If you want to use Python 2

1. Remove `print()`'s parenthesis: `if sentence == "have a nice day":`
2. Replace `input()` by `raw_input()`: `sentence = raw_input("Enter the sentence: ")`

Which gives this Python 2 program:

```
import random

sentence = raw_input("Enter the sentence: ")
sentence=sentence.lower()
languages=[['hello','goodbye','thank you',"you\'re welcome",'have','a','nice','day','how','are','you'],
               ['ola','Tehau','obrigado','seja bem-vindo','ter','uma','bom','dia','como','esta','voce'],
               ['hello','faida','Asante','karibu','kuwa na','a','nzuri','siku','vipi','ni','wewe'],
               ['hallo','Vaarwel','dank je','graag gedaan','habben','een','leuk','dag','hoe','ziin','u'],
               ['hola','adios','gracias','De nada','tener','un','bonito','dia','como','son','tu']]
t=''

if sentence == "have a nice day":
    words=sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        i=languages[0].index(word)
        r=random.randint(1,4)
        t+=languages[r][i]+' '
elif sentence == "goodbye":
    i=languages[0].index(sentence)  
    r=random.randint(1,4)   
    t+=languages[r][i]
elif sentence == "hello":
    i=languages[0].index(sentence)
    r=random.randint(1,4)  
    t+=languages[r][i]
elif sentence == "you're welcome":
    i=languages[0].index(sentence) 
    r=random.randint(1,4)
    t+=languages[r][i]
elif sentence== "thank you":
    i=languages[0].index(sentence)
    r=random.randint(1,4)
    t+=languages[r][i]
elif sentence== "how are you":
    words=sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        i=languages[0].index(word)
        r=random.randint(1,4)
        t+=languages[r][i]+' '

print "The translated sentence is", t
```